# Angularjs change background color

Tags: angularjs

In the following  code, on click of the td the color is changed for the td,but when someother td is clicked the old td color remains how to clear all td colors.I cannot use jquery or angular-jquery

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in myrows">
   <td style="width:100px;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getorder($event,r.id)" style="display:inline-block;">{{r.title}}</a></td
</tr>

$scope.getorder = function($event,release_id)
{
    console.log($event.currentTarget.parentNode);
    td = $event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    $event.currentTarget.parentNode.backgroundColor="red";

}
```

Comment: Hello :) could you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve?
Is it that when you click on first `td` it turns to a colour, and when you click on another `td`, it changes colour whie all other `td`s are back to white?

Comment: when i clieck on second td or third td...i want all other td to turn white

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it by in angular way by using [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) or [`ng-style`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle),

define scope variable in controller,

```
$scope.clickedElm = -1;
```

change the `ng-click` to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getorder($event,r.id); $parent.clickedElm = $index"...
```

and use `ng-class` in  tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="getorder($event,r.id); $parent.clickedElm = $index" ng-class="{differentBg : ($index == $parent.clickedElm)}"...
```

> Note : You need to call scope variable `clickedElm` by `$parent.clickedElm` because `ng-repeat` directive create a child scope in each and every iteration.

here is the [sample demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/I6HoVYKmcSCfxqq3ooAw?p=preview)

Comment: what does $index do here

Comment: Also how to hightlight the first td by default?

Comment: its the index of `ng-repeat` in first repeat `$index=0`, in second repeat `$index=1` likewise.. :)

Comment: change `$scope.clickedElm = -1;` to `$scope.clickedElm = 0;` :)

Comment: Also how to highlight td and not just the anchor tag

Comment: put `ng-class="{differentBg : ($index == $parent.clickedElm)}"` in the `td` tag and remove that from `<a>` :) http://plnkr.co/edit/5Y1j9AGL1bxRNIFMyFu0?p=preview